# SteamVR_Controller could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am trying to create a Pokemon Go clone in Unity following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XH942mANiv4). However, I'm trying to also make it work in VR with SteamVR.

However, following the guide to the Vive on Wenderlich's website here (https://www.raywenderlich.com/792-htc-vive-tutorial-for-unity), I get the following error:

Assets/Scripts/ViveControllerInput.cs(7,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SteamVR_TrackedObject' could not be found. Are you missing 'Valve.VR' using directive?

I am dragging the ViveControllerInputTest onto both controllers, but I still get this compile error.

Without the script, I am able to put on the headset and see the controllers and walk around.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

With the release of version 2.0 of the SteamVR Unity Plugin, Valve have updated the code to use the new SteamVR Input system (removing the previous Controller system). More info:

- https://steamcommunity.com/games/250820/announcements/detail/1696059027982397407
- https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1416820276

You can either:

- update your project to use the new SteamVR Input system, or
- download a previous version of the SteamVR Unity Plugin from Github and manually add it to your project. For example, version 1.2.3 of the SteamVR Unity Plugin can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steamvr_unity_plugin/releases/tag/1.2.3

Comment: If you want to spend your time creating your game, rather than fixing SteamVR, you'd better stay away from version 2 for now!